# how to fill combo in modal open not on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, combobox

I have a modal containing a combobox,this combobox is populated from database, i want the combobox filled when the modal is opened not on page load,how can this be done?

```
div class="modal fade" id="modal-DeleteFrm">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" style="width:300px;">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h3 class="modal-title">Delete Farmer</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="well" style="margin-bottom: 0px;padding: 10px;">
                <div>
                    <label class="Modallabel">Farmer Name:</label>
                </div>
                <div>                           
                    <select style="width:100%;background-color: #101d49;color:#ffffff;padding-bottom: 5px;" name="FarmerName" id="FarmerName">
                        <option value="">Select Farmer Name</option>
                        <!--populate value using php-->
                            <?php
                                 $stmt ="SELECT * FROM Farmers";
                                 foreach ($conn->query($stmt) as $row) {
                                    $FarmerName = $row['first_name_'].' '.$row['last_name_'];
                            ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $row['Farmer_ID'];?>"><?php echo $FarmerName;?></option>
                            <?php
                                }
                            ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button id="submitbtn" name="submitbtn" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-md" style="text-align:center;margin:0;width: 75px;" onclick="DeleteEntry('DeletedFarmer')">Delete</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-md" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="CancelModal()" style="text-align:center;font-weight: bold;">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As you have used php code to make `<option>` it will be populated when page renders. But if you want to get it updated when the popup is called, you can do that using ajax. You can fetch updated options with ajax and append new options instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a callback to your modal opening event as this code. Then populate your select into it:

```
$('#modal-DeleteFrm').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  // write your codes here...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be doing an ajax request when the modal button is clicked. i.e.

```
$('.modal-DeleteFrm.').on('click', function(){
    $.ajax([
      url: YOUR-POST-URL 
      dataType: json,
      method: POST,
      success: function() {
         // Do your appending here
      }
  ])
})
```

Which would send a POST request and return the data back as JSON. 
You could then append this to your modal form using javaScript .append()